# NSURL completion event is not being called

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently starting to learn swift.
My first "test-app" is a simple application, which does a NSURL Session request on startup and displays the received data in a tableview.
So far, my tableView does work and also my request method runs without any compilation errors.
My problem now is, that the event handler is not being called:

```
func doRequest(url: String) -> String
{
    var url = NSURL(string: url);
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    var config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration();
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: config);
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        println("CALLED");
    });
    return "";
}
```

The above method doesn't print anything into the console.
Since using google did not help me to find a solution, I try my luck here.
What's the issue with my code? Am I doing something wrong without realising it?

The URL for my tests is: [api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/leagueTable](http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/leagueTable)
which returns a simple json object.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `task.resume()` to start the download.
After you create the task, you must start it by calling its resume method.

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    println("CALLED");
});
task.resume()
```

Comment: Wow, how could I miss this. Works perfectly fine now, thank you.

Comment: Will have to wait another minute ;)